# Finding the folder of a previous visited page

Tags: javascript, html

I've recently found out that you can get the url of the previous visited page using `document.referrer`. However I've got a folder with a a large amount of pages which I'll be increasing over time. How can I check if a user was located from that folder when entering a new page instead of listing out every page?

Jonathan

Comment: the url will contain folder name just split string with '/' and ignore part not required

Comment: Be warned that `document.referrer` is not a very consistent way to know the previous visited page. It is only filled in if the user clicked a link in the browser to get to the page. But if the user bookmarks the page or copies the URL, then when they visit that page again by loading the bookmark or pasting the URL, `document.referrer` will be empty. So don't rely on it for critical behavior.

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSingla i got it working. Rory, i'm not requiring it to do that, I only want to know a few specific pages a user could have come from within my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @ShubhamSingla 's advice, i did this:

```
var prevPage = document.referrer; //The previous visited page.
var prevPageFolder = prevPage.split("/"); //Splitting the string to an array of substrings.
var pageNameIndex = prevPageFolder.length - 1;
prevPageFolder[pageNameIndex] = ""; //Select string to remove
route = prevPageFolder.join("/"); //Recreate the link without the name of the page.
//check to see if the link matches:
if (route == "www.mysite.com/something/somethingelse/") {
    //Whatever it is you want to do.
}
```